# newline or linebreak in a table

Tags: line-breaking, tabularx

I already searched for this problem but no solution worked for me...

Is there an easy way to get a linebreak in a cell of a table?

I just like to hyphenate `Gleitführung` to: `Gleit- \newline führung`.

```
\begin{table}[htb!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l||X|X|}
\hline
 & \textbf{\large Vorteile} & \textbf{\large Nachteile}\\
\hline

\textbf{Gleitführung} & \vspace{-0,6cm}
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=-4pt]
\item blablabla
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\end{itemize}

&

\vspace{-0,6cm}
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=-4pt]
\item blablabla
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\end{itemize}
\\
```

Already tried some solutions with `\parbox`, `\mbox`, ... did not work.

Comment: you have specified that coloumns 2 and 3 are parboxes with line breaking (X, which is p{...} wheer the line breaking liength ... is automatic) but the first column l is one line, like \mbox. also tex does not hyphenate the first word of a paragraph so you need `\hspace*{0pt}` before the word.

Answer (score 5):

There is no line break in the word "Gleitführung" since you're using the `l` column type for the first column. The width of the `l` column is simply that of the widest cell in that column.

To allow automatic line breaking along with proper hyphenation in this column, I suggest you (a) switch to the `p` column type with a suitably chosen width and (b) enable hyphenation by issuing a `\RaggedRight` directive as well as a `\hspace{0pt}` directive in the setup of this column. And, just in case you're not already doing this, you will also need to load the `babel` package with a suitable language option -- most likely, `ngerman`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,enumitem,ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} % for a more "open" look
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
     |>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{1.5cm}|
     |X|X|}
\hline
 & \bfseries\large Vorteile & \bfseries\large Nachteile\\
\hline
\textbf{Gleitführung}
&
\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*]
\item blablabla
\item blebleble
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*]
\item bliblibli
\item blobloblo
\end{itemize}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: BIG thanks man! Thats a pretty smart solution!

Answer (score 4):

With an `l, c, r`column type, you can use the | `\makecell` or `\thead` commands from the `makecell` package, which was designed for that, and a common formatting of column heads. I would also use `hhline` and slightly modify the list parameters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,enumitem,ragged2e, makecell, hhline}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellset{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt} % for a more "open" look
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l| |X|X|}%
\hhline{|-||--|}
 & \thead{Vorteile} & \thead{Nachteile} \\
\hhline{|-||--|}
 \makecell[lc]{Gleit-\\führung}
&
\begin{itemize}[topsep=1pt, itemsep=1pt, leftmargin=*, after=\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}]
\item blablabla
\item blebleble
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}[topsep=1pt, itemsep=1pt, leftmargin=*, after=\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}]
\item bliblibli
\item blobloblo
\end{itemize}\\
\hhline{|-||--|}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A variant of nice Bernard answer, in which the package `cellspace` is used for more vertical space in cells and `itemize` settings is collected in `\setlist{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cellspace, hhline, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellset{\bfseries}
%\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
˙%\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\setlist[itemize]{nosep, topsep=1pt, itemsep=1pt, leftmargin=*,
                  before=\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}}                          
                  after =\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}}% <-- itemize settings
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}% <-- cells' vertical space settings
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}% <-- cells' vertical space settings
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Sl| |X|X|}% <-- Sl is column type which consider vertical spaces added by "cellspace" package
\hhline{|-||--|}
 & \thead{Vorteile} & \thead{Nachteile} \\
\hhline{|-||--|}
 \makecell[lc]{Gleit-\\führung}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item blablabla
\item gagagaga
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item bliblibli
\item blobloblo
\end{itemize}\\
\hhline{|-||--|}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a hack but you can define a tabular inside a tabular:

```
\begin{table}[htb!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l||X|X|}
\hline
 & \textbf{\large Vorteile} & \textbf{\large Nachteile}\\
\hline

\begin{tabular}{c}\textbf{Gleit}\\\textbf{führung} & \vspace{-0,6cm}
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=-4pt]
\item blablabla
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\end{itemize}

&

\vspace{-0,6cm}
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=-4pt]
\item blablabla
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\end{itemize}
\\
```

Comment: if you do that (quite common for headings) you should use `@{}c@{}` on the inner tabular otherwise you get duplicated `\tabcolsep` padding one set from the inner table and another from the outer.